# Why onmouseout called every option change while inside select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The multiple select option call onmouseout function for every option change without come out from select box, May I know the reason for this event issue?

Bug fixed while remove the `multiple` attribute from the select tag.

```js
function mout(e){
        console.log("mouse is out");
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="x" multiple onmouseout="mout(this)">
        <option value="1">11:00 10-10-2017</option>
        <option value="2">11:00 10-10-2017</option>
        <option value="3">13:00 10-10-2017</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mouseleave`.

> The `mouseout` event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child
>   elements as well the selected element.
>
> The `mouseleave` event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves
>   the selected element.

```js
function mout(e){
        console.log("mouse is out");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="x" multiple onmouseleave="mout(this)">
        <option value="1">11:00 10-10-2017</option>
        <option value="2">11:00 10-10-2017</option>
        <option value="3">13:00 10-10-2017</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

On mouseout is similar to onfocusout; when select has `multiple` enabled the UI is such that onmouseout = onfocusout = onhover;

Same not in `multiple` disabled during which we have a traditional dropdown wherein onmouseout is triggered after `clicking, changing and then focusing out`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can be used `mouseleave` on jQuery.

```js
$( "#x" ).on( "mouseleave", function(e) {
    console.log("mouse is out");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<select id="x" multiple>
    <option value="1">11:00 10-10-2017</option>
    <option value="2">11:00 10-10-2017</option>
    <option value="3">13:00 10-10-2017</option>
</select>
```